# How to arrange the data of two 8-bits in to a single 16-bit in C?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have two 8-bit data,

> 1st 8-bit= {DA7 DA6 DA5 DA4 DA3 DA2 DA1 DA0}
>
> 2nd 8-bit= {DB7 DB6 DB5 DB4 DB3 DB2 DB1 DB0}

I wanted to merge these two data in to a single 16-bit data, as per the below arrangement,

> Expected result = {DB7 DA7 DB6 DA6 DB5 DA5 DB4 DA4 DB3 DA3 DB2 DA2 DB1
>   DA1 DB0 DA0}.

Is there any straight forward logic/method to achieve this in C?

Comment: for each bit you probably need to use an AND (`&`) and SHIFT (`<<`) operation, and OR (`|`) everything together.

Comment: `uint16_t i3 = i1 + ((uint16_t)i2 << 8);`?

Comment: [Bit Twiddling Hacks: interleave bits the obvious way](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3203764/33499) contains an algorithm

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combining two 8-Bit array to a USHORT (16 Bit) , without loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958360/combining-two-8-bit-array-to-a-ushort-16-bit-without-loop)

Comment: there are already tons of duplicates of this on SO. Read about bitwise operations first

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Some duplicates, yes, but the one you linked to is not one of them – the OP is looking to interleave the bits, not simply `a | b << 8`.

Comment: @Arkku from any duplicate he can easily combine the 2 8-bit values and write them to 16-bit int arrays

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc The OP is looking to do `interleave(0x00, 0xFF) == 0xAAAA`, the linked question is about `combine(0x00, 0xFF) == 0xFF00`.

Comment: @Arkku wrong, he's expecting  {DA7 DA6...} and {DB7 DB6...} into {DB7 DA7 DB6 DA6...} which is interleaving bytes, not bits

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Judging by the names `DA`/`DB` numbered `0…7` for the _8-bit_ sources, and the wording of the title (two 8 bits into a single 16 bit), and the pattern of the expected result (which is not an array of 16 bit ints), I'd say they are bits. Of course the OP can clarify their intent.

Comment: Oh now I know why each element in the 8-bit array has more than 8 bits like 0xDA7. The OP's wording made me thought that it's an array.

Comment: [Given 2 16-bit ints, can I interleave those bits to form a single 32 bit int?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4431522/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search keyword: “interleave bits”

There are many ways to do it, ranging from the “obvious” way to multiplying with magic numbers. See [bit twiddling hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#InterleaveTableObvious).

The obvious way adapted for 8-bit ints:

```
uint16_t interleave_bits(const uint8_t a, const uint8_t b) {
    uint16_t result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        result |= (a & (1U << i)) << i | (b & (1U << i)) << (i + 1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Inside the loop, `1U << i` masks each of the individual source bits in turn, bitwise-ANDing `&` it with `a` and `b` extracts that bit from the source variables, and the `<< i` and `<< (i + 1)` shift the bit to the target position. Then everything is just bitwise-ORed together `|`.

To clarify the shift to target position:

The `& (1U << i)` isolates the bit at index `i` from the input `a` and `b`. That bit is *already* in index `i`, so the *following* shift `<< i` for `a` puts it in index `i + i`, and the shift `<< (i + 1)` for `b` puts it in index `i + (i + 1)`. Thus a bit at index `i` ends up in index `2i` for `a` and in index `2i+1` for `b`.

An equivalent (but less efficient) implementation would be:

```
uint16_t interleave_bits(uint8_t a, uint8_t b) {
    uint16_t result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i, a >>= 1, b >>= 1) {
        result |= (a & 1U) << (2*i) | (b & 1U) << (2*i + 1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

In this second solution the source bit always starts at index `0`, thus the shifts show the target index directly (at the expense of hiding the source index and requiring modification of the arguments).

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but the answer seems to have a significant problem.  I.E. on first pass through loop, a.0 --> result.0 and b.0 --> result.1   On the second pass through the loop, a.1 --> result.1 etc.  suggest the right hand shift of each component be '2i' and '2i+1'

Comment: @user3629249 I've edited the answer to hopefully clarify this, it is indeed the convoluted part in this code. An alternative would be to keep using the lowest bit of `a` and `b` and then shift both _right_ by 1 bit on every iteration. This would make the left shifts `i * 2` and `i * 2 + 1`…